# DynamicServerError when deployed to Vercel but previous builds did not show this error. Is this the correct solution to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

I encountered this error when deploying my Next.js and Supabase project on Vercel. Strangely, even when attempting to re-deploy a previously functional version of the project, the error now appears, which was not the case earlier.

I am using this similar code in almost every page of mine:

```
const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });

  const {data: {session }} = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  if(!session){
     redirect('/login')
}
```

I did my research and added this to the `layout.tsx`

```
export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

However, I have also read in some posts/comments that this may or may not work depending on the use case. So to prevent any similar errors in the future. I would like to ask if based on my use case, is this really the correct approach in solving this error.

Addingt those codes on the `layout.tsx`, the DynamicServerError disappeared, however, this is what the new error shows when I tried deploying it again:
This is what it shows on Vercel:

[image]

My `npm run build` is this:

```
    FetchError: request to https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa2ZL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4017:801::2003:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:file here\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
}
FetchError: request to https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa2JL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4017:801::2003:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:file here\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
}
FetchError: request to https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1pL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4017:801::2003:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (Cfile here\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
}
Failed to compile.

app\layout.tsx
`next/font` error:
Failed to fetch `Inter` from Google Fonts.


> Build failed because of webpack errors
   Creating an optimized production build  .
```

Or is this because of the technical issue in Supabase right now?
[image]

Comment: Vercel is having troubles with deployments at the moment. Check their [status page](https://www.vercel-status.com/)

Comment: @FabioNettis So is it possible that the `DynamicServerError` was also caused by Vercel?

Comment: It is very possible, has the problem been resolved for you yet?